# Reference appsettings in TypeScript

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

Looking for advice on how I could make webservice api urls that are currently hard coded in my angular components/services configurable using the appsettings..json magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure your Angular application settings using the `environment.ts` file in the `app/environments` folder. For example

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:54162/'
};
```

You can use the setting in your services by importing

```
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
```

and then access the setting by doing something like

```
this.ApiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
```

Also note that you can setup environment files for different builds, `environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://[some production url]:54162/'
};
```

by default the `ng build command` will make use of the `environment.ts` file (Making the assumption that you are using Angular CLI of course)

For more information on how to setup environment files, read the following very useful article [Application Settings using the CLI Environment Option](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/)

Answer (score -1):

Create TS interface that contains all app settings. Then create token for that interface. Then provide Object, that implements interface...

```
export interface IAppSettings{
    backendUrl: string;
}

export const APP_SETTINGS = new InjectionToken<IAppSettings>('IAppSettings');

export class AppSettings implements IAppSettings{
    backendUrl: string = "http://example.com/";
}

@NgModule({
...
providers: [
    {provide: APP_SETTINGS, useClass: AppSettings} //`useClass` doesn't work in AOT???
]
...
})

@Component({})
export class MyAwesomeComponent{
    constructor(@Inject(APP_SETTING) private appSettings: IAppSettings){
    }
}
```

How exactly properties will be resolved inside of `AppSettings` - doesn't matter. You can even do backend request and add getters to extract data from shared source...